# key difference between $locationStartChange and $routeStartChange

Tags: javascript, angularjs

key difference between $locationStartChange and $routeStartChange ? I know their calling order. but are the two servs any different purpose or functionality ? whats the difference(If any) between them?

Answer (score 0):

**$locationChangeStart**

The locationChangeStart event can be used to prevent a location change going forward, (a click on a link or an explicit $location.path(“/something”); however, this event does NOT fire upon a back button click.

**$routeChangeStart**

This event works kinda like the opposite of $locationChangeStart: it is fired both on $location.path() changes and Back button clicks, but its preventDefault() will not stop the location change.

`$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart",function(event, next, current){
    //do your validations here
    //prevent the location change.
    event.preventDefault();
});`

`$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart",function(event, next, current){
    //do your validations here
    event.preventDefault();//this will NOT work.
});`

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** their is a different.

**$locationChangeStart** - get callback each time URL is start changing.

**$routeChangeStart** - get callback when registered route called or any of his own URL parameters.

```
$routeProvider.when("/books/:book_id?read", {
  controller: "yourController",
  templateUrl: "/views/test.html"
});

$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
 });

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {
 });

$location.search('read', 'true');     // will trigger both
$location.search('unread', 'true');   // just $locationChangeSuccess
$location.path('/books');             // will trigger both
```